# Safari web-inspector (CSS editor) is extremely bugged

Tags: css, debugging, safari, web-inspector

Safari's web-inspector -more specifically the CSS editor- is extremely bugged. In the example below I entered `font-size: 0.8em;` and hit enter, but nothing changed on the website and the code I just entered disappears. So I decide to enter the same code again, but after I hit enter now this happens:

[image]

**Here's what I know so far:**

- It always happens in the exact same order. First try nothing happens and the code disappears. Second try the code shows up like in the image.
- Most of the time, the list of "bugged code" is just a few rows and I can remove it to try again. On some rare occasions the "bugged code" is 100-200 rows.
- Usually, after 2-5 tries, the code will no longer get bugged and the changes will apply to the website I'm using web-inspector for. It just takes a couple of tries.
- This *only* happens in Safari. All other browsers I installed, such as Chrome and Firefox, still work without any issues. No bugged web-inspector at all.
- The bug *can* happen with all CSS properties, so it doesn't have to be `font-size`. Also `margin` and basically any other code does this exact same thing.
- Every single website I tried is susceptible to this bug, so it doesn't just happen on one of my own little projects. It's a real Safari bug I believe.
- It only happens to CSS properties. So any other website element I attempt to change, including CSS selectors, do not become bugged at all.
- I'm not 100% certain about this, but it seems to happen only to CSS properties that (partly) require numbers as input, such as 0.9em, 85%, 16px, etc.

Safari is up-to-date, but I have no idea for how long I've been experiencing this issue. It's been at least 6 months now and I've sort of "learned to live with it". But now I'd really like to resolve this issue and I have no idea what could possibly cause this. On Safari I have no extensions or anything installed. Just a plain and simple Safari installation.

Did anybody experience the same issue?

How do I solve this?

Comment: Am I the only one having this issue? I'd sort of expect more people to have this. Very strange!

Comment: I absolutely also am having this issue. Safari 15.5 on Monterey. It's so frustrating!

Comment: I have the issue with chrome based browsers (Chrome Dev Tools)

Comment: maybe try this new one called safari preview https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Comment: No, you're not the only one. However, even in Chromium-based browsers, I find the CSS editing interface extremely counter-intuitive so I only use it in the rarest of circumstances.

Comment: Yeah I debug in Safari most of the time, and I experience this from time to time. Other issues too, where the properties are not showing but still applied. But it only happens after editing, onLoad it is pretty accurate.

Comment: The only way to fix a Safari bug is to [report it to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) and hope that they act on it.

Comment: I’m voting to close because this is not a question, it's someone having a whinge about browser bugginess.

Comment: I'm asking how to solve this bug. Unfortunately it seems like there is no solution just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you clear cache and reinstall safari.
here is how to clear cache.

In the Safari browser:
Click on the Safari menu in the top left hand corner next to the Apple symbol.

Click on Settings...

A new dialogue box will open.
Click Privacy.

Click on the Manage Website Data button.

To remove any cached data and cookies from your computer, click Remove all.

Also, make sure you are referring to the proper span heading blog correctly.

Hope this helps.